# Ringer is adjusting, not the Volume

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, volume

I am building an app. In this app, when I change the volume using side buttons the **ringer** is getting adjusting, not the **volume**. The interesting thing is, when I power off/on the device it is working fine as expected. Volume is getting adjusted.  Can anyone tell what is the problem?

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure that's how it's meant to work. App volume is adjusted via control centre on the music/app audio panel.

Comment: As I mentioned,the interesting thing is, when I power off/on the device it is working fine as expected.

Comment: I don't quite understand sorry. You change the volume during power on/off?

Comment: After power on/off, when I run my app again, Volume(not ringer) is changing   as expected.